# Stronger Gravity for Particles

Tags: particles

I am working on an ejecting shells animation using particles, and I have to crank up the normal setting in order to make them coming out fast enough.  However, this causes the gravity to not be strong enough to pull them to the ground until an eternity later.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Here's what it looks like:

[image: particles]

the 3d widget is where the plane which ejects the particles is.  Due to how much velocity the shells have (normal settings are high), they just keep going up, as shown by the red line.  I would prefer them to fall a lot sooner, as shown by the green line.

Here are my settings:

[image: Settings1]

[image: Settings2]

Comment: You can certainly modify the values for gravity in the field weight section, but if you can also increase the mass for the particles in the pysics settings

Comment: To me, the gravity setting in the weight section is simply a switch for turning it on or off.

Comment: No picture? or is this going to be a guessing game?

Comment: check the edit.

Comment: Ok guessing game, I'm not a big fan of those... how about the picture of the settings?

Comment: Back to comment one. Now you can see the settings for gravity (in field weight) and mass (in newtonian physics). Play with those. The default for gravity is 1 but you can type in a value to change that to a higher number.

Comment: Oh!  I didn't realize the gravity settings went higher than one... probably forgot.  Thanx for bearing with me!